# Kibana 3 can't connect to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have tried to setup a kibana 3 with elasticsearch and logstash.

When i go to 127.0.0.1/kibana i get following error:
`Error Could not contact Elasticsearch at http://127.0.0.1:9200. Please ensure that Elasticsearch is reachable from your system.`

And when I check the console log i get the following:
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

When I go to the url http://127.0.0.1:9200 i get the following JSON text

```
{
  "name" : "Meteor Man",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.1.1",
    "build_hash" : "40e2c53a6b6c2972b3d13846e450e66f4375bd71",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-12-15T13:05:55Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.3.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

and in http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes I get the following:

```
{"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","nodes":{"BKXqqrymQw6lShg5P7_-eA":{"name":"Meteor Man","transport_address":"127.0.0.1:9300","host":"127.0.0.1","ip":"127.0.0.1","version":"2.1.1","build":"40e2c53","http_address":"127.0.0.1:9200","settings":{"client":{"type":"node"},"name":"Meteor Man","pidfile":"/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid","path":{"data":"/var/lib/elasticsearch","home":"/usr/share/elasticsearch","conf":"/etc/elasticsearch","logs":"/var/log/elasticsearch"},"config":{"ignore_system_properties":"true"},"cluster":{"name":"elasticsearch"},"foreground":"false"},"os":{"refresh_interval_in_millis":1000,"name":"Linux","arch":"amd64","version":"3.19.0-25-generic","available_processors":4,"allocated_processors":4},"process":{"refresh_interval_in_millis":1000,"id":10545,"mlockall":false},"jvm":{"pid":10545,"version":"1.7.0_91","vm_name":"OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM","vm_version":"24.91-b01","vm_vendor":"Oracle Corporation","start_time_in_millis":1453983811248,"mem":{"heap_init_in_bytes":268435456,"heap_max_in_bytes":1038876672,"non_heap_init_in_bytes":24313856,"non_heap_max_in_bytes":224395264,"direct_max_in_bytes":1038876672},"gc_collectors":["ParNew","ConcurrentMarkSweep"],"memory_pools":["Code Cache","Par Eden Space","Par Survivor Space","CMS Old Gen","CMS Perm Gen"]},"thread_pool":{"generic":{"type":"cached","keep_alive":"30s","queue_size":-1},"index":{"type":"fixed","min":4,"max":4,"queue_size":200},"fetch_shard_store":{"type":"scaling","min":1,"max":8,"keep_alive":"5m","queue_size":-1},"get":{"type":"fixed","min":4,"max":4,"queue_size":1000},"snapshot":{"type":"scaling","min":1,"max":2,"keep_alive":"5m","queue_size":-1},"force_merge":{"type":"fixed","min":1,"max":1,"queue_size":-1},"suggest":{"type":"fixed","min":4,"max":4,"queue_size":1000},"bulk":{"type":"fixed","min":4,"max":4,"queue_size":50},"warmer":{"type":"scaling","min":1,"max":2,"keep_alive":"5m","queue_size":-1},"flush":{"type":"scaling","min":1,"max":2,"keep_alive":"5m","queue_size":-1},"search":{"type":"fixed","min":7,"max":7,"queue_size":1000},"fetch_shard_started":{"type":"scaling","min":1,"max":8,"keep_alive":"5m","queue_size":-1},"listener":{"type":"fixed","min":2,"max":2,"queue_size":-1},"percolate":{"type":"fixed","min":4,"max":4,"queue_size":1000},"refresh":{"type":"scaling","min":1,"max":2,"keep_alive":"5m","queue_size":-1},"management":{"type":"scaling","min":1,"max":5,"keep_alive":"5m","queue_size":-1}},"transport":{"bound_address":["127.0.0.1:9300","[::1]:9300"],"publish_address":"127.0.0.1:9300","profiles":{}},"http":{"bound_address":["127.0.0.1:9200","[::1]:9200"],"publish_address":"127.0.0.1:9200","max_content_length_in_bytes":104857600},"plugins":[]}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to [enable CORS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html) in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file and restart ES, that setting is disabled by default.

```
http.cors.enabled: true
```

However, I'm not certain that Kibana 3 will work with ES 2.1.1. You might need to upgrade your Kibana in order for this work. Try to change the above settings and see it it helps. If not, upgrade Kibana to the latest release.

Comment: The error in the console got solved but I still get the error `Could not connect Ealsticsearch` I really hoped that I would get it work because it was so simple with just run it as a website.

Maybe it's just for the best to upgrade the whole thing.

Comment: Both adding that line and upgrading to the latest Kibana made it work.